# Probability space defined by moment ambiguity set is a compact set ?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

In this paper *Applying the minimax criterion in stochastic recourse programs*, it says that if $\mathscr{A}$ is the class of all probability measures with support in some compact set $\Xi$, satisfying a number of generalized moment conditions, $\int\Xi g_i(\xi)\mu(d\xi)\leq \alpha_i,i=1,\cdots,L$, where $g_i(),i=1,\cdots,L$ are bounded continuous function on $\Xi$, then $\mathscr{A}$ is a compact, convex set.

Convexity on $\mathscr{A}$ is easy to check. However, I am not quite understand why $\mathscr{A}$ is compact.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Compact with respect to what topology?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think it is weak convergence topology or total variation.. However, the paper does not point out explicitly. Is there any other topology that would make the set compact?

Comment: The class of all probability measures with support in a compact set form a compact set under weak convergence and the stated inequalities give a closed subset of this compact set. However, since you have not given much information where these measures are defined this cannot be taken as a precise answer. [when you talk about measures with compact support it is important to know the space and the sigma algebra on which these are defined].